# Ubuntu 16.04.1 spotty wifi

Tags: wireless

I posted here yesterday about my new install having no wifi, but somehow I got it working and was enjoying it all last night until I booted it and went to sleep. I boot it up this morning and back to the original problem, I don't understand how it can work one day, and the next it doesnt. I dropped OSX for this and it's equally if not more frustrating . My specs include : MBP mid 2010, bcm4332 wif, Ubuntu 16.04.1.

Command:

```
chris@chris-MacBookPro:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4322 802.11a/b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller [14e4:432b] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. AirPort Extreme [106b:008d]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
--
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM5764M Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:1684] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM5764M Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:1684]
    Kernel driver in use: tg3
    Kernel modules: tg3
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: It's a common current trending bug of 16.04 lts

Comment: Okay so i found a fix so far. If i boot my computer and the wifi is disconnected i just reboot again and it usually works, unsure why "service network-manager restart" doesnt work but hopefully the bug is fixed soon so i can fully enjoy this OS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install a newer proprietary driver. Run in terminal

```
sudo apt purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt install broadcom-sta-dkms
```